# Get Sitecore page content dynamically

Tags: sitecore-api

I'm trying to get a page's content dynamically so I can open in a modal. What's the best way of getting the html from a page given an ID/page url?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail to help people understand you requirement?

Comment: sure @AmitabhVyas - I have a list of links that point to sitecore content pages. When a link is clicked, I want to get the pages' content and display it in a different format (ex Modal window).

Comment: Why not use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) passing in the page url (and window options for modal) or use an iframe and set the `src` property rather than scraping HTML from Sitecore...?

Comment: thats a good suggestion @jammykam but I wont render all the renderings on the page (Header, footer etc) so I'd like to have control over the different renderings that are to be displayed

Comment: instance of using link you can use the ID of content page and by ID you can get item and all the fields of the that item, you can get item by the link field as well.

Comment: Thanks @MahendraShekhawat - That's what I'm trying to achieve. I can get the content page in sitecore from my link, but I need is to get all the renderings + datasources to display in a modal. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: @Snapper If you get _just_ the markup and display it on another site, you will need to expand all links to be absolute otherwise images/css/javascript links will not be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the suggestion which is provided by @jammykam. To fit to your requirements I would create a new device and there you can create your own layout for that specific modal.
You can create your device under `/sitecore/layout/Devices`:

[image]

Then your new device will apear in the **Layout Details**:
[image]

Then you can access to the device related rendering defintion through the following url: **http://[url]?sc_device=modal**

Comment: Exactly how we do things too. We typically create a slimmed down layout file specifically for modals too.